# what is this syntax mean? operator overloading & throw exception

Tags: c++, throw

Saw piece of code in book:

```
T& operator[](int i) throw(RangeError)
{
    if(i >= 0 && i < sz) return ptr[i];
    throw RangeError();
}
```

what does the throw(RangeError) mean?  Behind a function declaration, I know we can append const, or =0 (for pure virtual), but I have never seen throw(...)

Comment: I found exception-specification section after several pages in that book -_-#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is an [exception-specification](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr156.htm). It means that your function tells everyone that it has a limited list of things it can throw. Unfortunately or not, but nothing prevents you actually throwing anything else from the function, but if something unexpected is thrown at runtime, then `unexpected()` will be called. Exception specifications have been removed in the new C++ standard.

```
void f() throw(); //I promise not to throw anything
void g() throw(A, B, C); // I promise not to throw anything except for A, B, or C
```

Unlike const-qualifiers, an exception specification is not part of a function's type.

Comment: Note: By default unexpected() causes the application to terminate with extreme prejudice.

Answer (score 3):

It is an [exception specification](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill22.htm). It tells the compiler that the function may only throw expections of the type `RangeError` or subtypes thereof.